# Exporting R dataframes in excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, package, export-to-excel

I want to work using the fbRanks package in R, that's a package built to rank football/soccer teams and predict the number of goals during a match.

After I read the [pdf manual][1] describing that package provided by the author, I still don't understand how  I can build the dataset in order to start analysing data.

In order to understand how the author built the dataset, I want to export the dataframe he used to do the analysis in an excel spreadsheet.

I already nstalled the xlsx package that should allow to do this, but, when I run

> write.xlsx(dataframe_name, "path_in_windows")

R gives an error:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'B00scores' not found

even if the dataframe exists.

Can somebody help me?

I'm not an expert user of R; if the question is not clear, please comment below.

Comment: Use `library(fbRanks); data(B00data)`. This will make two data sets available for use, `B00.scores` and `B00.teams`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @nrussell but I know how to load data, while I want to know how to build that data and replace the analysis of Dixon & cole using a different dataset. For instance, running the command str(B00.scores) you get all the dataset columns. I would like to know how to build that data using a raw dataset available at http://www.football-data.co.uk/data.php

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question, apologies.

Comment: So is your question title wrong? You're not interested in just "seeing" the data? Do you just not know how to read any data into R?

Comment: Yes @MrFlick, I'm a new R user and I'm at the beginning.I will edit  the title if you can suggest the proper one.

Comment: Then i suggest reading the `?read.table` help page because that's  the primary function to import data into R. The official R projected provides the [R Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html) manual for further discussion on getting data into and out of R.

Comment: I want to export the data the package author imported as example to use the package, not importing some files.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but how a solution like [here](http://science.nature.nps.gov/im/datamgmt/statistics/r/fundamentals/index.cfm) does not answer your question? Or reading ?write.csv documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggest that not only have your installed the package but that you jave also loaded it into the current session. You should have offered code that showed how you created the object with the name 'dataframe_name', but we can see from the error that it had the value "B00scores". Again you should have shown how `B00scores` was created since is does not exist after:

```
> data('B00data', package='fbRanks')

> str(B00scores)
Error in str(B00scores) : object 'B00scores' not found
```

As it turns out,  you are misspelling the name:

```
> str(B00.scores)
'data.frame':   2031 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ date      : Date, format: "2012-05-25" "2012-05-25" ...
 $ home.team : chr  "PacNW Blue B00" "WA Rush Swoosh B00" "Crossfire Premier B B00" "Normandy Park FC White B00" ...
 $ home.score: num  0 1 12 4 1 10 0 4 7 5 ...
 $ away.team : chr  "Normandy Park FC White B00" "PacNW Maroon B00" "WA Rush Swoosh B00" "WA Rush Nike B00" ...
 $ away.score: num  8 7 0 0 8 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ venue     : chr  "PacNW Memorial Cup 2012" "PacNW Memorial Cup 2012" "PacNW Memorial Cup 2012" "PacNW Memorial Cup 2012" ...
 $ home.adv  : chr  "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" ...
 $ away.adv  : chr  "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" "neutral" ...
 $ surface   : chr  "Grass" "Grass" "Turf" "Grass" ...
```

So unlike the two voters to close for lack of clarity, I think the close vote should be for misspelling.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for the stupid question but I'm new in R, as I wrote down in the question. Now I solved! :)